# How to calculate these gamma functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Equation : $$\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{n}e^{-x}dx=n!=\Gamma(n+1) $$

1) $$ \int _{0}^{1}x^{2}\left( \ln \dfrac {1} {x}\right) ^{3}dx $$

2) $$\int _{0}^{1}\sqrt[3] {\ln x}dx $$

Hint : $$ x=e^{u} $$

3)Express as a Gamma Function.

$$ \int _{0}^{1}\left[ \ln \left( \dfrac {1} {x}\right) \right] ^{p-1}dx $$

Comment: welcome to math@SE. Please tell us where the problem is from (homework perhaps?) and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Erbil As the hint says, try plugging in $x=e^u$. You will be able to immediately recognize it in terms of $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: I removed the tag functional-analysis, and added integral, gamma-function instead.

Comment: I think the hint pretty much gives it away.  Erbil, you should explain what happened when you tried that substitution.

Comment: M. L. Boas-Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences - John Wiley (Chapter 11,Problems Sections 3) 
Here is the all questions. http://physicsforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=54658&d=1358013518 
2) I have found it from table.
3) I have used recursion and table to find it.
4) Again With recursion.
5)Γ(0.7)= 1/p(p+1) with this formula.
8) IfGamma(p+1) is equal to this integral,I think it can be written as Gamma(2/3+1)

11) $$ \int _{0}^{\infty }x^{2}e^{-x^{2}}dx=2\int _{0}^{\infty }u^{2}e^{-u}du=2\cdot \Gamma 3 $$ 
NO idea for these questions.

Answer (score 4):

$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 x^2 \ln^3 (1/x)dx = \int_{\infty}^{0} e^{-2t} \ln^3(e^t) \times -e^{-t} dt}_{x = e^{-t}} = \overbrace{\int_0^{\infty} t^3 e^{-3t} dt = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{z^3}{27} e^{-z} \dfrac{dz}3}^{t = z/3} = \dfrac{\Gamma(4)}{81}$$

$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{\ln(x)}dx = \int_{\infty}^{0} \sqrt[3]{(-t)} \times - e^{-t} dt }_{x = e^{-t}} = - \int_0^{\infty} t^{1/3} e^{-t} dt = - \Gamma(4/3)$$

$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 \sqrt[p-1]{\ln(1/x)}dx = \int_{\infty}^{0} \sqrt[p-1]{t} \times - e^{-t} dt }_{x = e^{-t}} = \int_0^{\infty} t^{1/(p-1)} e^{-t} dt = \Gamma(p/(p-1))$$

Comment: Marvis,thanks for this useful answer.I just can't understand how we find t^3 in question one.And how can I figure intervals of integral.

Comment: @Erbil $\ln(e^t) = t$. Hence, $$\ln^m(e^t) = (\ln(e^t))^m = t^m$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marvis. ...And how can I figure intervals of integral....

Comment: @Erbil Note that under the transformation $x=e^{-t}$, for $x=0$ we need $e^{-t} = 0 \implies t = \infty$. Similarly, under the transformation $x=e^{-t}$, for $x=1$ we need $e^{-t} = 1 \implies t = 0$.

Comment: Okay,thanks for this great explanation.Finally,did you forget a minus on question one?

Comment: @Erbil No. Note that as I removed the negative sign the limits got interchanged as well. In general, $$\int_a^b - f(x) dx = \int_b^a f(x) dx$$

Comment: Oh,That's right.Thanks again.I hope see you again on my new questions.